# Mapping a Domain Model to a Zend Form

Tags: design-patterns, zend-framework, zend-form, datamapper

I have a Domain Model and a Form and I have always found it tricky to Map one to the other. I've never really liked passing an instance of a mapper to a form.

Does it make sense to create a Form Mapper that uses the Domain Model Mapper to set form defaults? Or should I create a method on the form that accepts a DomainModel that sets the defaults?

The drawback for option 1 is the FormMapper has a dependence with the DomainModelMapper and the drawback for option 2 is that the controller gets fatter.

```
class DomainModel
{
    function toArray() {}
}

class DomainModelMapper
{
    function findById($id)
    {
        return new DomainModel($id);
    }
}
```

The FormMapper uses the DomainModelMapper to populate MyForm.

```
class MyForm extends Zend_Form
{

}

class FormMapper
{
    function getFormById($id)
    {
        $mapper = new DomainModelMapper();
        $domainModel = $mapper->findById($id);

        $form = new MyForm();
        $form->setDefaults($domainModel->toArray());

        return $form;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by mapping i.e. what is the relation between form and domain model and is domain model an instance of `zend_db_table_abstract`

Comment: DomainModel is separate to the Database Object http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html, I have omitted Database layer for simplicity

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to do this on your controller file. After all, you are going to display the form

```
public function someAction()
{

    $mapper = new DomainModelMapper();
    $domainModel = $mapper->findById($id);

    $form = new MyForm();
    $form->populate($domainModel->toArray());
    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

I think you can do this on your `view.phtml` file also.

I am not quite sure about your requirement. But what I do in zf is something like this and quite easy and tricky.

1. Name all form fields according to database table fields like if I have table with fields `f1, f2, f3, ..` then my form elements names are `f1, f2, f3, ..`
2. So when I retrieve data form database via `Db_Model` then I populate using `$form->populate($dbmodel->toArray())` while editing.
3. While inserting or updating I get the array form form. `first remove all non-db fields like submit buttom` then `then $data = $form->getValues()` and `$dbmodel->udpate($data, 'where condition')`

I am not sure at all if I address your problem, but Zend certainly makes my work lot easier with few nasty freaking obstacles so I don't use any database mapper (at least with zend).

Comment: Yeah that's option 2. I may have over simplified the example, in reality setting the default values will need a little tweaking.

Comment: @gapertron of course you can do tweaking on the controller file

Comment: If you ever needed to reuse the form in another situation, you would end up duplicating the tweaks. Also your database fields names may not always match your Domain Models properties.

Comment: @gaperton yes that absolutely true and perfectly logical to do if you have large no of tweaks to do, but if you are doing few tweaks, then it's a small price to pay

Comment: I've seen people add a method to the form class, something like `setDefaultsFromModel($model)`. Then in your controller, it's one call to instantiate the form, one call to the mapper to fetch your entity, and a third call to set form defaults using the model. In my view, that controller is pretty reasonable. If not, then you can push some of that down into a service class (which is passed your mapper to do its access).

Comment: @David Weinraub: That's more or less how I'm approaching it for the time being. What would you do in reverse?

Comment: Another alternative is to have the [model create the form](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/200-Using-Zend_Form-in-Your-Models.html), although the intention here is more to use the form as a validator, keeping the code DRY.

Comment: @gawpertron I think the better way would be to pass variables to zend form class

Comment: @David Yes I have tried it this way as well, but this seems to tie Zend_Form to the Model, which isn't ideal in some situations, especially if you need to use multiple Models to construct the Form.

Comment: I largely agree with @gawpertron: pass array data into the form. After all, `$form->setDefaults($data)` expects an array. It would be nice to have a way to pass a model(s) into the form, but that makes the form overly-aware of the models from which it gets data. Alternatively, it would be nice to have a method on your models that exports array-data for a form, but then models seem to be overly-aware of the forms in which the the model's data will be used. So maybe a third class to intermediate between each form and each model?